# best practice for parsing a complex json string

Tags: c#, json, parsing, yql

I am in the process of learning C#, and decided to try parsing some JSON as a project. I'm using the JSON.NET package, which has made it really easy. I'm wondering if there is a better way to get to the elements deeper inside the JSON, instead of using something like [object].[innerObject].[innerinnerObject].[innerinnerinnerObject].name

Here is the JSON in question (obtained from [Yahoo YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+%2a+from+weather.forecast+where+woeid%3D2502265))

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 1,
  "created": "2013-11-06T04:18:34Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "diagnostics": {
   "publiclyCallable": "true",
   "url": {
    "execution-start-time": "0",
    "execution-stop-time": "106",
    "execution-time": "106",
    "content": "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2502265"
   },
   "user-time": "108",
   "service-time": "106",
   "build-version": "0.2.1997"
  },
  "results": {
   "channel": {
    "title": "Yahoo! Weather - Sunnyvale, CA",
    "link": "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Sunnyvale__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA1116_f.html",
    "description": "Yahoo! Weather for Sunnyvale, CA",
    "language": "en-us",
    "lastBuildDate": "Tue, 05 Nov 2013 7:55 pm PST",
    "ttl": "60",
    "location": {
     "city": "Sunnyvale",
     "country": "United States",
     "region": "CA"
    },
    "units": {
     "distance": "mi",
     "pressure": "in",
     "speed": "mph",
     "temperature": "F"
    },
    "wind": {
     "chill": "61",
     "direction": "0",
     "speed": "0"
    },
    "atmosphere": {
     "humidity": "52",
     "pressure": "30.19",
     "rising": "1",
     "visibility": "10"
    },
    "astronomy": {
     "sunrise": "6:37 am",
     "sunset": "5:06 pm"
    },
    "image": {
     "title": "Yahoo! Weather",
     "width": "142",
     "height": "18",
     "link": "http://weather.yahoo.com",
     "url": "http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif"
    },
    "item": {
     "title": "Conditions for Sunnyvale, CA at 7:55 pm PST",
     "lat": "37.37",
     "long": "-122.04",
     "link": "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Sunnyvale__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA1116_f.html",
     "pubDate": "Tue, 05 Nov 2013 7:55 pm PST",
     "condition": {
      "code": "33",
      "date": "Tue, 05 Nov 2013 7:55 pm PST",
      "temp": "61",
      "text": "Fair"
     },
     "description": "\n<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/33.gif\"/><br />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />\nFair, 61 F<BR />\n<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />\nTue - Mostly Clear. High: 72 Low: 48<br />\nWed - Partly Cloudy. High: 75 Low: 51<br />\nThu - AM Clouds/PM Sun. High: 68 Low: 49<br />\nFri - Partly Cloudy. High: 66 Low: 45<br />\nSat - Sunny. High: 64 Low: 46<br />\n<br />\n<a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Sunnyvale__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA1116_f.html\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>\n",
     "forecast": [
      {
       "code": "33",
       "date": "5 Nov 2013",
       "day": "Tue",
       "high": "72",
       "low": "48",
       "text": "Mostly Clear"
      },
      {
       "code": "30",
       "date": "6 Nov 2013",
       "day": "Wed",
       "high": "75",
       "low": "51",
       "text": "Partly Cloudy"
      },
      {
       "code": "30",
       "date": "7 Nov 2013",
       "day": "Thu",
       "high": "68",
       "low": "49",
       "text": "AM Clouds/PM Sun"
      },
      {
       "code": "30",
       "date": "8 Nov 2013",
       "day": "Fri",
       "high": "66",
       "low": "45",
       "text": "Partly Cloudy"
      },
      {
       "code": "32",
       "date": "9 Nov 2013",
       "day": "Sat",
       "high": "64",
       "low": "46",
       "text": "Sunny"
      }
     ],
     "guid": {
      "isPermaLink": "false",
      "content": "USCA1116_2013_11_09_7_00_PST"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I have my classes mapped accordingly:

```
public class WeatherInfo
{
    //top level query object
    public jsonquery query { get; set; }
}

public class jsonquery
{
    public jsonresults results { get; set; }
}

public class jsonresults
{
    public jsonchannel channel { get; set; }
}

public class jsonchannel 
{
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

With the way it's set up right now, this is how I'm getting the title "Yahoo! Weather - SunnyVale, CA"

```
Console.WriteLine(wInfo.query.results.channel.title);
```

This seems rather unnatural and can become hard to read. Is there a better way for me to call those deep JSON elements?

Comment: Your concern for the current way isn't clearly described by the question. Are you worried about execution time navigating through the object tree, expense of parsing the complex JSON object, or something else?

Comment: I'm most worried that the way I'm currently doing it isn't good coding practice, since there could be a lot of repetitive code and could cause some readability issues down the road. Using [object].[innerObject].[innerinnerObject].[innerinnerinnerObject].name seems way too long. The answer below looks like a good way to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split this up into multiple lines to keep from having long lines of repetitive code.  for example:

```
var channel = wInfo.query.results.channel;
var title = channel.title;
var link = channel.link;
```